# What is the evidence for preantepenultimate stress?

Tags: stress, old-latin, prosody

I've seen it mentioned before that, in Plautus's era, words of the form LLLX (such as *gĕnĕrĭbŭs*) would be stressed on the fourth syllable from the end. In other words, *géneribus* rather than Classical *genéribus*.

My question is, though—what is the evidence for this? [This answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29971/10559) mentions a few sources for the rule, but I haven't found any that explain *how we know* it was a rule, or give more than one example.

Comment: Not a full answer but FWIW, Weiss's discussion of this question is rather skeptical. He mentions the ictus theory you allude to in the linked answer but says it's unclear whether ictus really aligned with stress; he also cites the syncope *balineae > balneae*, but calls it "a rather thin reed to hang a theory on".